# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0

Tags: java, api, ssl

im interacting with mercadolibre API which its java client library can be found here:
https://github.com/mercadolibre/java-sdk

These are the instructions for authenthication:

This is a 2 step process.

1. First get the link to redirect the user. This is very easy! Just:

   ```
   String redirectUrl = m.getAuthUrl("http://somecallbackurl");
   ```

   This will give you the url to redirect the user. You need to specify a callback url which will be the one that the user will redirected after a successfull authrization process.
2. Once the user is redirected to your callback url, you'll receive in the query string, a parameter named code. You'll need this for the second part of the process.

   ```
   m.authorize("the received code", "http://somecallbackurl");
   ```

   This will get an accessToken and a refreshToken (is case your application has the offline_access) for your application and your user.

At this stage your are ready to make call to the API on behalf of the user.

When i do the `m.authorize()`

I get the following error:

```
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [jsp] en el contexto con ruta [/JAJA] lanzó la excepción [Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP /index.jsp en línea 20

17:     
18:     String u=(String)request.getParameter("code");
19:     if(u!=null){
20:         m.authorize(u, "http://localhost:8082/JAJA");
21:         Log.log(m.getAccessToken());
22:         return;
23:     }


Stacktrace:] con causa raíz
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.checkRecordVersion(InputRecord.java:552)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:565)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:529)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.jdk.JDKAsyncHttpProvider$AsyncHttpUrlConnection.call(JDKAsyncHttpProvider.java:240)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Im Using JDK 8 and tomcat 8

This is the Meli Class, with is the hole java client:

```
package com.mercadolibre.sdk;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig;
import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.BoundRequestBuilder;
import com.ning.http.client.FluentStringsMap;
import com.ning.http.client.Response;

public class Meli {
    public static String apiUrl = "https://api.mercadolibre.com";
    private String accessToken;
    private String refreshToken;
    private Long clientId;
    private String clientSecret;
    private AsyncHttpClient http;
    {
        AsyncHttpClientConfig cf = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
                 .setUserAgent("MELI-JAVA-SDK-0.0.1").build();
        http = new AsyncHttpClient(cf);
    } 

    public Meli(Long clientId, String clientSecret) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
    }

    public Meli(Long clientId, String clientSecret, String accessToken) {
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
    }

    public Meli(Long clientId, String clientSecret, String accessToken,
        String refreshToken) {
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
    this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
    }

    public String getAccessToken() {
    return this.accessToken;
    }

    public String getRefreshToken() {
    return this.refreshToken;
    }

    public Response get(String path) throws MeliException {
    return get(path, new FluentStringsMap());
    }

    private BoundRequestBuilder prepareGet(String path, FluentStringsMap params) {
    return http.prepareGet(apiUrl + path)
        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .setQueryParameters(params);
    }

    private BoundRequestBuilder prepareDelete(String path,
        FluentStringsMap params) {
    return http.prepareDelete(apiUrl + path)
        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .setQueryParameters(params);
    }

    private BoundRequestBuilder preparePost(String path,
        FluentStringsMap params, String body) {
    return http.preparePost(apiUrl + path)
        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .setQueryParameters(params)
        .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").setBody(body)
        .setBodyEncoding("UTF-8");
    }

    private BoundRequestBuilder preparePut(String path,
        FluentStringsMap params, String body) {
    return http.preparePut(apiUrl + path)
        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .setQueryParameters(params)
        .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").setBody(body)
        .setBodyEncoding("UTF-8");
    }

    private BoundRequestBuilder preparePost(String path, FluentStringsMap params) {
    return http.preparePost(apiUrl + path)
        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .setQueryParameters(params);
    }

    public Response get(String path, FluentStringsMap params)
        throws MeliException {
    BoundRequestBuilder r = prepareGet(path, params);

    Response response;
    try {
        response = r.execute().get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MeliException(e);
    }
    if (params.containsKey("access_token") && this.hasRefreshToken()
        && response.getStatusCode() == 404) {
        try {
        refreshAccessToken();
        } catch (AuthorizationFailure e1) {
        return response;
        }
        params.replace("access_token", this.accessToken);
        r = prepareGet(path, params);

        try {
        response = r.execute().get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MeliException(e);
        }
    }
    return response;
    }

    private void refreshAccessToken() throws AuthorizationFailure {
    FluentStringsMap params = new FluentStringsMap();
    params.add("grant_type", "refresh_token");
    params.add("client_id", String.valueOf(this.clientId));
    params.add("client_secret", this.clientSecret);
    params.add("refresh_token", this.refreshToken);
    BoundRequestBuilder req = preparePost("/oauth/token", params);

    parseToken(req);
    }

    public String getAuthUrl(String callback) {
    try {
        return "https://auth.mercadolibre.com.ar/authorization?response_type=code&client_id="
            + clientId
            + "&redirect_uri="
            + URLEncoder.encode(callback, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return "https://auth.mercadolibre.com.ar/authorization?response_type=code&client_id="
            + clientId + "&redirect_uri=" + callback;
    }
    }

    public void authorize(String code, String redirectUri)
        throws AuthorizationFailure {
    FluentStringsMap params = new FluentStringsMap();

    params.add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
    params.add("client_id", String.valueOf(clientId));
    params.add("client_secret", clientSecret);
    params.add("code", code);
    params.add("redirect_uri", redirectUri);

    BoundRequestBuilder r = preparePost("/oauth/token", params);

    parseToken(r);
    }

    private void parseToken(BoundRequestBuilder r) throws AuthorizationFailure {
    Response response = null;
    String responseBody = "";
    try {
        response = r.execute().get();
        responseBody = response.getResponseBody();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new AuthorizationFailure(e);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        throw new AuthorizationFailure(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new AuthorizationFailure(e);
    }

    JsonParser p = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject object;

    try {
        object = p.parse(responseBody).getAsJsonObject();
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        throw new AuthorizationFailure(responseBody);
    }

    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {

        this.accessToken = object.get("access_token").getAsString();
        JsonElement jsonElement = object.get("refresh_token");
        this.refreshToken = jsonElement != null ? object.get(
            "refresh_token").getAsString() : null;
    } else {
        throw new AuthorizationFailure(object.get("message").getAsString());
    }

    }

    private boolean hasRefreshToken() {
    return this.refreshToken != null && !this.refreshToken.isEmpty();
    }

    public Response post(String path, FluentStringsMap params, String body)
        throws MeliException {
    BoundRequestBuilder r = preparePost(path, params, body);

    Response response;
    try {
        response = r.execute().get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MeliException(e);
    }
    if (params.containsKey("access_token") && this.hasRefreshToken()
        && response.getStatusCode() == 404) {
        try {
        refreshAccessToken();
        } catch (AuthorizationFailure e1) {
        return response;
        }
        params.replace("access_token", this.accessToken);
        r = preparePost(path, params, body);

        try {
        response = r.execute().get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MeliException(e);
        }
    }
    return response;
    }

    public Response put(String path, FluentStringsMap params, String body)
        throws MeliException {
    BoundRequestBuilder r = preparePut(path, params, body);

    Response response;
    try {
        response = r.execute().get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MeliException(e);
    }
    if (params.containsKey("access_token") && this.hasRefreshToken()
        && response.getStatusCode() == 404) {
        try {
        refreshAccessToken();
        } catch (AuthorizationFailure e1) {
        return response;
        }
        params.replace("access_token", this.accessToken);
        r = preparePut(path, params, body);

        try {
        response = r.execute().get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MeliException(e);
        }
    }
    return response;
    }

    public Response delete(String path, FluentStringsMap params)
        throws MeliException {
    BoundRequestBuilder r = prepareDelete(path, params);

    Response response;
    try {
        response = r.execute().get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MeliException(e);
    }
    if (params.containsKey("access_token") && this.hasRefreshToken()
        && response.getStatusCode() == 404) {
        try {
        refreshAccessToken();
        } catch (AuthorizationFailure e1) {
        return response;
        }
        params.replace("access_token", this.accessToken);
        r = prepareDelete(path, params);

        try {
        response = r.execute().get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MeliException(e);
        }
    }
    return response;
    }

    public BoundRequestBuilder head(String path) {
    return null;
    }

    public BoundRequestBuilder options(String path) {
    return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't getting that exception from this code. This code uses HTTP, not HTTPS, and none of it appears in this stack trace.

Comment: i know what you say, but nothing in that stacktrace is my code, i now edited it with the client java class, there is everything in that class.